# How to access service method in ngOnInit?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am new to Angular 2 and Typescript and I am expirmenting with the constructor and with ngOnInit.

[from this stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/jldobgeejyn?file=app%2Fsidenav-responsive-example.ts)

How come I can use `matchMedia` in the constructor in the following:

```
import {MediaMatcher} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Responsive sidenav */
@Component({
  selector: 'sidenav-responsive-example',
  templateUrl: 'sidenav-responsive-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidenav-responsive-example.css'],
})
export class SidenavResponsiveExample {
  mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;

  private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

  constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher) {
    this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }
```

But when I try to use `matchMedia` in ngOnInit, I get `ERROR TypeError: layout_1.MediaMatcher.matchMedia is not a function`:

```
import {MediaMatcher} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Responsive sidenav */
@Component({
  selector: 'sidenav-responsive-example',
  templateUrl: 'sidenav-responsive-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidenav-responsive-example.css'],
  providers: [MediaMatcher]
})
export class SidenavResponsiveExample implements OnInit {
  mobileQuery: MediaQueryList;
  mobileQuery = {matches:false};
  foo: MediaMatcher;


  private _mobileQueryListener: () => void;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mobileQuery = MediaMatcher.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }
```

I know a constructor is used for initialization and is a better fit than ngOnInit. I am just experimenting and would to know how to do the same in ngOnInit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the dependecny in the constructor (with access modifier ) and then access  the property using `this`

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eujv5e?file=app/sidenav-responsive-example.ts)**

```
 constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,private media: MediaMatcher) {

      }
    ngOnInit(){
      this.mobileQuery = this.media.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
        this._mobileQueryListener = () => this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
    }
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.mobileQuery.removeListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
      }

      shouldRun = [/(^|\.)plnkr\.co$/, /(^|\.)stackblitz\.io$/].some(h => h.test(window.location.host));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to inject the `MediaMatcher` through the constructor and call it using `this`

```
constructor(changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, media: MediaMatcher) {
    this.mobileQuery = media.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mobileQuery = this.media.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)'); // use this
    this._mobileQueryListener = () => ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    this.mobileQuery.addListener(this._mobileQueryListener);
  }
```